# Run specflow acceptance test cases via TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, nunit, specflow

I have created Automated tests using Gherkin and specflow that uses NUnit internally. The tests are running successfully when launched from Visual Studio.

I am trying to run the tests from TFS 2015, however, it is throwing the error.

[image]

[image]

This is the configuration I have done in build step.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the path to the custom test adapters if they're installed as NuGet packages. Beyond that, the error you're seeing is because the `packages` folder doesn't exist in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. It's probably in a subfolder.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I removed custom test adapters. Now its showing this error:    -> error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I can see its permission issue but don't know which account to give access. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For the **error: 80070005**. The build agent usually runs in a Windows Service and not in an Interactive window. That gives it some restrictions when it comes to loading and running  Applications. And the user that is hosting the Build Agent might also be a restricted user with limited rights to file system and certain COM/ActiveX controls.

So, you can try to change the TFS build server to run as a user with admin rights (Build Agent service account).

And you can also try below things for troubleshooting.

- running the build on your local machine from the commandline under your account.
- running the build on the build server from the commandline under your account.
- running the build on the build server from the commandline under the build server account

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for help, but I am unable to find TFS build server service. At most I am able to see Visual Studio Team Foundation Background job agent. I am using TFS 2015 Update 3. I changed the service account to administrator but no use. Please help.